# How to wrapAll the content in a particular height?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have one question is there is any way to wrapp a particular height content in jquery the following is my requirement I hope someone will help me to this problem

```
  <p>Ligula mi volutpat porta consectetur in varius quisque at mus dignissim in felis felis ultricies ullamcorper ornare per vestibulum diam nibh id. A ridiculus scelerisque felis id eget dictumst a parturient amet blandit suspendisse vulputate vitae ullamcorper nullam ante eu sit fermentum vivamus nisi ridiculus lobortis.<p>
```

If this content reaches to the particular height the content which is covering the height it should be in the one group and excess content should wrapp into another div group is it possible?

Comment: Use css - give fixed height and use CSS properties - `overflow:hidden` and `text-overflow:ellipsis`

Comment: `text-overflow: ellipsis` only works on a single line. If you want a particular height, then you'll have to use jquery or similar

Comment: I found solution for my problem into this https://jsfiddle.net/2w9hk616/4/ thanks for your response RehbanKhatri an melvindidit

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer for my Question

**HTML**

```
          <div class="record">some element
        <br/>content</div>
      <div class="record">some element
        <br/>contentsome element
        <br/>contentsome element
        <br/>content</div>
      <div class="record">some element
        <br/>content</div>
      <div class="record">some element
        <br/>contentsome element
        <br/>contentsome element
        <br/>contentsome element
        <br/>contentsome element
        <br/>content</div>
      <div class="record">some element
        <br/>contentsome element
        <br/>content</div>
      <div class="record">some element
        <br/>contentsome element
        <br/>content</div>
      <div class="record">some element
        <br/>contentsome element
        <br/>content</div>
      <div class="record">some element
        <br/>contentsome element
        <br/>content</div>
```

In your Function

```
        var $records = $('.record'),
      total = 0,
      group = 0,
      limit = 200; //px

    $records.each(function() {
      var $record = $(this);
      total += $record.outerHeight(true);

      if (total > limit) {
        total = $record.outerHeight(true);
        group++;
      }
      //$record.attr('data-height', $record.outerHeight(true));
      //$record.attr('data-total', total);
      $record.attr('data-group', group);
    });

    for (var i = 0; i <= group; i++) {
      $('[data-group="' + i + '"]').wrapAll('<div class="page"></div>')
    }
```